# Matlab: How can I get an image handle for a matrix to be used in createMask?

Tags: matlab

I'm working with netCDF matrices representing satellite imagery.  I'm trying to make a binary mask so I can analyze ROIs within the matrix.  I've made an imellipse to use as the mask.

Now, the function createMask requires an image handle for the underlying data.  How can I get an image handle for my data matrix? I've displayed in as a contourf plot.

Comment: I ended up taking a different route, but thanks for the reply!

Comment: please consider posting an answer of your own, so that users can utilize it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The *createMask()* function works without an image handle as well. To get the binary mask just do like this:

```
imshow(Img,[]);
e = imellipse();
mask = createMask(e);
```

If you want to do it using an image handle, you can create an image handle by doing:

```
h_img = imshow(Img,[]);
```

You can then use this handle in the *createMask()* function. (But it is not really neccesary)

Comment: I ended up taking a different route, but thanks for the reply!